# Querying a table based on a global "search" criteria: how to write my where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

My back end service is receiving a global "search" criteria from a single field and I need to apply it on my table. The behaviour requested is that each white space in the search field is considered a separator. So in the end I receive an array of criterias to apply on every field in my db table.

A row should only be included if all the values are found in a row, no matter in which columns as they are not specified (it is, as I said, a global search field)

```
WHERE [column] in ([searchcriterias])
```

should be the SQL applied on every column.

But what about the link between each columns? I can not make an "AND" (that would mean each column has to have one of the value provided), but not an "OR" either, because that would include rows with, for example, only one column containing only one of the value, when in the end a row should only be included if all the searched values have been found (no matter in what columns).

How should I write my query?

Comment: Impossible to answer without more detail. And I suggest you start by creating 2 simple (but different) examples of what one might find in [searchcriteria], the rows against which you want to apply this value (again - a simple, small set of both inclusive and exclusive values), and the expected result. If you don't know whether to use "or" or "and" it seems you are not yet ready to code any solution. Usually it helps to just write a few simple examples to help visualize a solution

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Please include some sample data of the table you are searching and the criteria you need to search by as well as desired results from that sample data after the search has been done. It sounds like maybe you might want to concatenate all of your columns (yuck) and apply your search criteria to that: `WHERE col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 LIKE ANY ('%searchterm1%', '%searchterm2%', '%searchterm3%')` ?

Comment: I think that you can do the opposite of what you describe. meaning - search any one of your terms in all the relevant columns. `... WHERE term1 IN (col1, col2 , col3...) AND term2 in (col1, col2 , col3...) AND ...`

Comment: in this way you'll get TRUE only if all of your terms are in the record.

Comment: Thanks Adirmola, I think this is going to do the trick actually ! I'll try today.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to design a dynamic SQL.

I would do the following:

1. Select the condition into cursor

   DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM YourTable
2. While there are values in cursor concatinate conditions with `AND` into a varchar variable
3. Execute the result query using `sp_executesql`

[Declare and use cursor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[sp_executesql docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)